# htaccess remove php extension and redirect index

Tags: .htaccess

In my site ( all .php files ) I want to use htaccess to :

a) Remove .php extensions

b) Redirect index.php to www.mysite.com ( along with index )

I have search in stackoverflow and i come up with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#Rewrite index.php back to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
```

Which does part of the job but can't see how to correct this :

a) If I load ( in browser ) the page www.mysite.com/about it show correctly the page about.php. But if I load www.mysite.com/about.php it does not remove the .php extension which for google this are 2 different pages.

b) If I load ( in browser )  the page www.mysite.com/index.php it goes to www.mysite.com which is what i want but if load www.mysite.com/index I have some problem as it shows the same page but cant see how to remove the index part here. So again, and for google i have 2 different pages.

Hope I can explain correctly my problem.
In resume the htaccess is working but can't see how to tune it as i wanted.

( obs: internal links between pages in my site are made ... href="about">About Us... )

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edited again

Try

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/^(.*)$\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks nyne but seems that now all calls are now with the .php extension even if i only put www.mysite.com/about ( it adds the .php extension )
for the index it was corrected, i mean, if i pu www.mysite.com/index it goes to www.mysite.com

could be something in the order of the lines in the htaccess or maybe I was not able to explain correctly my problem? thanks

Comment: thanks again nyne; .. same situation, if i write in browser www.mysite.com/about.php it does not remove the .php ...